# can not realize what is wrong with: $ echo ‘`date`’

Tags: shell, command-substitution

What happens when the following command is executed? Explain why, and how to fix it:

```
$ echo ‘`date`’
```

Comment: Did you mean to use curly quotes? What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: Why don't *you* tell us what happened? You're the one who ran the command, after all. What did you see? What were you expecting to see instead?

Answer (score 7):

I’m guessing you’re running

```
echo '`date`'
```

(note the straight single quotes) and expecting to see `date`’s output. The shell never expands strings inside single quotes; you should use double quotes instead:

```
echo "`date`"
```

or just drop them

```
echo `date`
```

All this is equivalent to

```
date
```

though, apart from the shell splitting and globbing (as pointed out by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)), which will collapse blanks by default.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `echo \`date\`` is not the same as `date`. The former means calling the split+glob operator on the output of `date`. With the default value of `$IFS`, that will squeeze sequences of blanks into one space. See also with `export TZ='***0'` on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

**As posted**, the outer quotes are Unicode U+2018 and U+2019 characters. These are NOT regular single quotes and have no special meaning to shell and are simply echoed:

```
$ echo ‘`date`’
‘Fri Apr 7 19:55:15 EEST 2017’
$
```

Inside these quotes are backticks for shell command substitution. The `date` command is executed and the captured output replaces the `date` string.